# How to remove a number in a list if it equals 0. Python

Tags: python

I'm adding two lists together, and if the sum of one of the added elements = 0, I must remove it from the list. The numbers have to carry over if they hit over 10. So far this is what I've gotten:

```
list = [1,2,1]
list2 = [2,18,9]

SumOfLists = [x+y for x,y in zip (list, list2)]

if SumOfLists[2] >= 10:
    SumOfLists[2] -= 10
    SumOfLists[1] += 1
if SumOfLists[1] >= 10:
    SumOfLists[1] -= 10
    SumOfLists[0] +=1


if SumOfLists[0,1,2] == 0:
return SumOfLists[0,1,2] != 0
```

The last part doesnt work. How do I fix this, and have them print out with '/' in between, and not as [1,2,3]

Comment: I won't know the specific values. In the assignment I'm adding two list inputs. Is there a way to do break the list apart and then tell it to separate using '/'  ?

Comment: It looks like you're simulating base 10 addition. Should `list2` contain the element 18, considering you probably want to be working with digits?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension with a condition to get rid of the 0, and then join on the `'/'` character:

```
mylist = [1,3,0,5]
result = '/'.join([str(x) for x in mylist if x != 0])
```

Comment: Use this, then you can call `'/'.join(result)`

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [str(n) for n in old_list if n]
print '/'.join(new_list)
```